# How to compare the 30th to last row of data to the last row of data

Tags: r

In R I pull in a time series and conduct a pair analysis. I want to compare the last row of the data to 30 days earlier and see the percentage change. I tried to use the `sweep` function but I can't get it work right. For Example:

OK, so for example, let's just use last 6 lines of my matrix.

```
2019-03-15 0.3916652    
2019-03-18 0.3872261     
2019-03-19 0.3858074     
2019-03-20 0.3848039     
2019-03-21 0.3810281    
2019-03-22 0.3804672
```

Would I use the `sweep` function for this? If so, How? I know if my data matrix is labeled i

```
sweep(i, 1, )
```

Just not sure what to do from there.

Any help would be great,

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the `dput` of the example and your expected output

Comment: Hi, I get an error when outputing as expected since I am not sure how to use the sweep function. What I would want the output to be:
-2.71% ( % difference of .391 to .3804)

Answer (score 0):

How about just `print(head(tail(df,30),1))` and `print(tail(df,1))`

Edit: Actually, the solution was just that the OP needed to convert his matrix into a data.frame.

Comment: That works, but trying to calculate the percent difference doesn't work. It will pull out the line but it gives me the wrong calculation everytime I do (x - y) / y

Comment: Are you sure you are doing `(tail(df[,2],1) - head(tail(df[,2],30),1))/head(tail(df[,2],30),1)`

Comment: Hi Corey, Yes I am positive. One thing to note is that df[,2] is unecessary since the dates you see above are technically a time stamp. They are not their own column. When taking out this df[,2] and putting in the calculation I receive this as my answer:

Data:
numeric(0)

Index:
numeric(0)

Comment: @jbs Have you tried converting from matrix to data.frame? Try `df <- as.data.frame(df)` and then try printing the head and tail.